# how to scale data values of a dataset without changing average

Tags: scaling

I have a dataset. Now I want to scale them to have a new variance.
So:
new-data-value = old-data-value / sigma_old * sigma-new.

But with this method, the average changes too. How can I make average fixed?

Answer (score 1):

First, subtract the mean, then do the scaling, then add the mean back again.

```
(old-data-value - mean) / sigma_old * sigma_new + mean
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mathematics basics. To simplify the problem here is a small description:

You have 2 integers `A` and `B`. The average is `C`. Now if you multiply `A` and `B` by `X` you will get `(XA + XB) / 2 = XC`.

The only way you can keep your `C` steady is to scale `A` up and scale `B` down.